# DPM 2010 System Protection Job fails because backup location unwriteable

Tags: scdpm

We have a Server 2008 R2 DC that runs as a virtual machine on a vmware host. We back this up using DPM 2010 and that backup has been running for ages.

Recently the backup started failing and the error on the DC is

The backup operation that started at '‎2011‎-‎04‎-‎11T07:51:50.959402800Z' has failed because the remote shared folder '\BMCBAC01.thebmc.local\810dc4298960497bb3544f2cf49bc2bf' that you are using for a backup storage location is not writeable. Please make sure user 'SYSTEM' has write permissions for this location, and then rerun the backup operation.

There is enough free space on the client to hold the backup image.

If I look in the share and storage management section of file services I can see that share is marked with a red x

Clicking properties against that item throws the error:

810dc4298960497bb3544f2cf49bc2bf

\?\c:\Program Files\Microsoft DPM\DPM\Volumes\Replica\Non VSS Datasource Writer\vol_e5907630-426a-4bc7-bc83-c699182bf185\810dc429-8960-497b-b354-4f2cf49bc2bf\Full\C-Vol: Cannot verify that the folder exists. Illegal characters in path.

I've reinstalled the agent and removed and readded the machine from the protection group all TNA

Any help appreciated

**UPDATE:**

I see in [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dataprotectionmanager/thread/cd1ef456-f9d4-4817-a88b-43c5ee95f9df/?prof=required) that an MS person has said that the illegal characters in path error is normal...

So we need to concentrate I guess on event ID 564 source Backup with text as above.

On the machine in question vssadmin list writers shows no writers with errors.

also

```
C:\Windows\system32>vssadmin list volumes

vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool

(C) Copyright 2001-2005 Microsoft Corp.



Volume path: \\?\Volume{60936920-a0cd-11df-af25-806e6f6e6963}\

    Volume name: \\?\Volume{60936920-a0cd-11df-af25-806e6f6e6963}\

Volume path: C:\

    Volume name: \\?\Volume{60936921-a0cd-11df-af25-806e6f6e6963}\
```

I note that the volume here doesn't match that on DPM but I'm guessing that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course the simplest solution is the actual solution. The error message in the event log had a link to the share. Clicking the link to launch explorer focused on the share showed that the WindowsImageBackup folder contained had only permissions for local administators.

I went up a level to \backupServer and viewed permissions on the share itself which were Domain Admins, System and Local Administrators *on this folder only*

I changed those permissions to this folder, subfolders and files and the consistency check and synchronisation has been running for about 7 minutes suggesting that it will run to completion.